# Only one mysqli_free_result with multiple mysqli_query

Tags: php

Can I use only one `mysqli_free_result` at the end of the page (PHP)? In the page I use multiple `mysqli_query` with distinct querys. For example:

```
$res= mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
...
$res= mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
...
$res= mysqli_query($conexion, $sql)
...
...
if ($res){@mysqli_free_result($res);}
```

Or I have to free result every time?

Comment: *"I use multiple mysqli_query with distinct querys"* - Seeing what you posted, doesn't seem distinct (to me) and are possibly being overwritten. The question's unclear for me in that respect.

Comment: My question is "unique mysqli_free_result" with multiple mysqli_query, I know that I can use multiple mysqli_query.